# How to move data from one column to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have following data:

```
            id                 date   oked_1     oked_2  KPS  address    type
225  001041004832         2000-10-12  71209     01111  105  196430100    3
225  001041004832         2000-10-12  71209     46211  105  196430100    3
225  001041004832         2000-10-12  71209     52101  105  196430100    3
```

i need to move "oked_2" to "oked_1" in a way that all other columns have to replicated. For example, below you can see how oked_2 values are copied to oked_1, while other column data are the same. I want to have only oked_1 for my final dataframe(all oked_2 data have to be moved to oked_1).I expect:

```
               id                 date   oked_1     oked_2  KPS  address    type
    225  001041004832         2000-10-12  71209     01111  105  196430100    3
    225  001041004832         2000-10-12  01111     46211  105  196430100    3
    225  001041004832         2000-10-12  46211     52101  105  196430100    3
    225  001041004832         2000-10-12  52101     52101  105  196430100    3
```

How can I do that? I have not tried, because I do not have any clue how to process it...

If you see the expected dataframe, you can clearly notice that values from oked_2 are copied to oked_1. Furthermore, because one row was added because there was 3 different values in oked_2 and one was in oked_1. Total 4 unique values.

Comment: explain the logic of the transformation, it is not clear from your question what logic or rules are you applying or what you mean by moving the data!

Comment: @Mutaz-MSFT I added some info. hope it helps

Comment: @UldanaDuisenaly Are you saying you want to copy/paste values of `oked_2` to `oked_1`?

Comment: @Xitiz I do not know how to explain with further details. If you see expected dataframe, you can clearly notice that values from oked_2 are copied to oked_1. Furthermore, because one row was added because there was 3 different values in oked_2 and one was in oked_1. Total 4 unique values.

Comment: Okay! You should provide this detail in your question!!

Comment: does df['oked_1'] = df['oked_2'] solves that if it true one to one copy

Comment: @Phani it does not solve

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: Also, if line 1 had as many tokens as subsequent lines, you could use the csv module (DictReader) to very easily process this. Having said that, reading the file and doing a bit of string manipulation should be trivial

Comment: @UldanaDuisenaly check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68507678/how-to-move-data-from-one-column-to-another/68508041#68508041), working as expected. Mark this as accepted answer if it completely solved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"oked_1":["71209","71209","71209"],"oked_2":["01111","46211","52101"]})

print(df)
"""
   oked_1 oked_2
0  71209  01111
1  71209  46211
2  71209  52101
"""
df.loc[len(df.index)] = df.loc[len(df.index)-1] 
  
df["aa"]=pd.unique(df[["oked_1","oked_2"]].values.ravel('K'))
print(df)
"""
  oked_1  oked_2
0  71209  01111
1  01111  46211
2  46211  52101
3  52101  52101
"""
```

I don't think I have completely understood you logic but it is giving expected result, as I understand.

Edit:  I have tested it with this dataset:

```
id,date,oked_1,oked_2,KPS,address,type
001041004832,2000-10-12,71209,01111,105,196430100,3
001041004832,2000-10-12,71209,46211,105,196430100,3
001041004832,2000-10-12,71209,52101,105,196430100,3
```

And the output is:

```
           id        date  oked_1  oked_2  KPS    address  type
0  1041004832  2000-10-12   71209    1111  105  196430100     3
1  1041004832  2000-10-12   71209   46211  105  196430100     3
2  1041004832  2000-10-12   71209   52101  105  196430100     3

           id        date  oked_1  oked_2  KPS    address  type
0  1041004832  2000-10-12   71209    1111  105  196430100     3
1  1041004832  2000-10-12    1111   46211  105  196430100     3
2  1041004832  2000-10-12   46211   52101  105  196430100     3
3  1041004832  2000-10-12   52101   52101  105  196430100     3
```

And it is working as expected!

Answer (score 1):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = """
_            id                 date   oked_1     oked_2  KPS  address    type
225  001041004832         2000-10-12  71209     01111  105  196430100    3
225  001041004832         2000-10-12  71209     46211  105  196430100    3
225  001041004832         2000-10-12  71209     52101  105  196430100    3
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), dtype=str, delim_whitespace=True)

df['oked_1'] = df[['oked_1', 'oked_2']].to_numpy().tolist()

df = (df.explode('oked_1')
        .drop_duplicates('oked_1', ignore_index=True)
        .drop('oked_2', axis=1)
     )
```

Output for `df`:

```
     _            id        date oked_1  KPS    address type
0  225  001041004832  2000-10-12  71209  105  196430100    3
1  225  001041004832  2000-10-12  01111  105  196430100    3
2  225  001041004832  2000-10-12  46211  105  196430100    3
3  225  001041004832  2000-10-12  52101  105  196430100    3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate data frames for oked_1 and oked_2 and then drop duplicates & combine the dataframe. As shown below.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, dtype = str) #this is your main dataframe

df1 = df.drop(columns = ['oked_2']).drop_duplicates(subset=['oked_1'])
df2 = df.drop(columns = ['oked_1']).drop_duplicates(subset=['oked_2']).rename(columns = {'oked_2': 'oked_1'})

data = pd.concat([df1,df2]).reset_index()
print(data)
```

which looks like this

```
   index          id        date oked_1  KPS    address type
0      0  1041004832  2000-10-12  71209  105  196430100    3
1      0  1041004832  2000-10-12  01111  105  196430100    3
2      1  1041004832  2000-10-12  46211  105  196430100    3
3      2  1041004832  2000-10-12  52101  105  196430100    3
```